# How to style a randomly generated list of items in Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, underscore.js

Using Underscorejs's sample method.

Is it possible to add css styles to the generated random sample? For example in the returned [1, 6, 2] array, how would I go about making all 3 returned numbers a different color?

> Code: (from UnderscoreJS)
>
> sample_.sample(list, [n])  Produce a random sample from the list. Pass
>   a number to return n random elements from the list. Otherwise a single
>   random item will be returned.
>
> ```
> _.sample([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 3);
> => [1, 6, 2]
> ```

Comment: why don't you add conditions? `if(returnNumber == 5) //make this list style to..` .

Comment: It's not clear what exactly you're asking. Do you want objects like `[{ n: 1, color: 'red' }]`? Do you want DOM elements like `['<span style="color:red">1</span>']`?

Comment: The numbers will be quotes eventually. Does that help JF?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope You are looking for a way to style them randomly.Please don't think this is the the best solution; you can create a variable to store random classes, and add them to the quote element; I achieved this using following code

```
    var my_res = _.sample([
        'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et',
        'Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab',
        'Li Europan lingues es membres del sam familie. Lor separat existentie es un myth. Por scientie, musica, sport etc, litot',
        'Far far away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries Vokalia and Consonantia, there live the blind texts. Separated',
        'A wonderful serenity has taken possession of my entire soul, like these sweet mornings of spring which I enjoy with',
        'One morning, when Gregor Samsa woke from troubled dreams, he found himself transformed in his bed into a horrible vermin.'
    ], 3);
    var my_class = _.sample(['style_1','style_2','style_3','style_4','style_5','style_6'],3)
    var arr_len = my_res.length;
    var targ = document.getElementById('i_need_quotes_within_this');
    for(i=0; i<arr_len; i++){
        targ.innerHTML += "<q class="+my_class[i]+">"+my_res[i]+"</q><br/>"
    }
```

I also Created A fiddle on [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net), You can view the fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/L2ytuoxe/3/). Please let me know if you find something troublesome

EDIT:

[HERE you GO](https://jsfiddle.net/uto6a7rj/). SORRY I didn't Understand the problem first time

Comment: Fantastic. That is very close to what I was looking for thank you! If I wanted them all to have one class how would I go about that?

Comment: you mean same their layout needs to be same.. just some minor differences like change in font color?? @AndrewLeonardi?

Comment: and let me know are you ok with using inline styling? if so. then you know it will be more than easy with given fiddle, but I can post one with same class, just minor differences done with them randomly using inline styling.

Comment: The goal is to have the each quote in a separate box. The boxes should be red. Thank you!

Comment: check it out now @AndrewLeonardi

Comment: NP. Buddy. It was pleasure. :)

Comment: One last question for you Syed. If I wanted to have the in rows of 4... how would I set the css to do this? Thank you!

Comment: I lied one more question. The goal is to be able to have click events on each individual quote. So if one red box is clicked it should turn green. Is this possible considering it's all one array? That along with the ability to have rows of 4 cards and I think I'm there! :)

Comment: Sorry I had a rough day. LOL. just life. some days good someday bad.. Do you still need answer?? or have you solved it?? actually I was bit busy with assignment I had to submit it today. and got exams coming up next week. and question do you want specific events??  or random like once first quote turns green and other time it turns red? and moreover do you want them to change color to different one when they are clicked? or toggle back to previous one? @AndrewLeonardi

Comment: and by rows you refer to rows created by grid system of bootstrap?? @AndrewLeonardi